# Are there problems in this code? Can someone explain how this works

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

This code is from sololearn.com in the JS course.

```
function person(name, age) {
  this.name= name;  
  this.age = age;
  this.yearOfBirth = bornYear;
}
function bornYear() {
  return 2016 - this.age;
}
```

`this.yearOfBirth = bornYear;` why is bornYear just bornYear?

Shoudn't it be bornYear()

How does this even work?

Comment: Yeah I agree it doesn't make sense, because the variable name `yearOfBirth` suggests the value is a int (there is no verb used for naming) and this is obviously a function

Comment: ... but yes, you can assign a function to a field of an object and call it later: `var p = new person('John', 20);  var dob = p.bornYear();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this version would help you better to understand and is probably what the teacher wanted to write:

```js
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name= name;  
  this.age = age;
  this.getYearOfBirth = function bornYear() {
    return 2016 - this.age;
  };
}
```

1- Always use Pascale case with a function that will be treated as class, that is why I renamed `person` to `Person`. That improves readability and confusions

2- I renamed `yearOfBirth` to `getYearOfBirth`, I agree the teacher should have given a better naming here too. Devs idiomatically use verbs to accessors (get/set) or methods (compute, parse, find...)

3- `bornYear` is a function within a class, so that an accessor is defined. Since `bornYear` is called without `new` operator, `this` will be equaled to `window` as default binding

Try it yourself, open your javascript console in the browser and type following:

`function t() { console.log(this); }`

`t()` returns `window`, the global/default scope

`new t()` returns a freshly created context `t`

Comment: ``` function Person(name, age) {
  this.name= name;  
  this.age = age;
  this.getYearOfBirth = function bornYear() {
    return 2016 - this.age;
  };
}
x = Person.getYearOfBirth
console.log(x) ``` I get undefined, why is that?

Comment: @user13806962 Because you need to instantiate the class so that `this` will point to a fresh context. The logic in the function becomes then the class constructor, and will be executed at instanciation using `new`. Try `function Person(name, age) { this.name= name; this.age = age; this.getYearOfBirth = function bornYear() { return 2016 - this.age; }; } var instance = new Person(); var x = instance.getYearOfBirth; console.log(x);`

Answer (score 0):

`bornYear` is a function.

`bornYear()` is a value returned by burnYear function and equals `2016-this.age`

What happens if `this.yearOfBirth = bornYear`

`this.yearOfBirth = bornYear` means you assign `this.yearOfBirth=function(){return 2016-this.age}`

Then lets say `var me = new person("john",16)` you can call `me.yearOfBirth(); // 2000`

What happens if `this.yearOfBirth = bornYear()`,

while you are declaring `var me = new person("john",16)` bornYear() was executed `return 2016-this.age` but this.age is not defined so returned undefined. Then, `this.yearOfBirth=undefined`.

Comment: So is bornYear the yearOfBirth property?

Comment: And how can this.age be used in the function?

Comment: The context `this` is passed down to `bornYear` function at assignment in `person`

Comment: bornYear is a function itself. We use this function to define method of the Object Constructor. So, bornYear is a function and this.yearOfBirth is a method.

Comment: You can imagine, bornYear is just a string and we passed it to this.yearOfBirth

Answer (score 0):

```
function person(name, age) {
  this.name= name;  
  this.age = age;
  this.yearOfBirth = bornYear;
}
function bornYear() {
  return 2016 - this.age;
}

var p = new person("A", 22);
document.write(p.yearOfBirth());
```

This code explains it.

A new object is created (new)

yearOfBirth is used because it returns a value

If you check the value, it's what it should be.

(Bad explaining)